# Simple python re lookahead help

Tags: python, regex

I have three sample twiki names:

`names = [ "JohnDoe", "JaneMcAdams", "BillyBobThorton" ]`

I want to get the following back:
   * John Doe
   * Jane McAdams
   * BillyBob Thorton

Now I have this which busts them apart on the cap (That's a good thing).

`re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', name)`

How do I ignore "Mc" as a split?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend against using a regex here. I doubt Mc is the only name particle you need to match.  Did you think about Mac, O, Van, Von, De?

I suggest to break them as you say you currently do and build the first name and last name manually.

Bonus. Regex:

```
re.findall('(?:Mc|Mac|O|Van|Von|De)?[A-Z][^A-Z]*', name)
```

But Van, Von, De should be separated with a space.

*Note: If you say you only want to match McSomething use the a short version `(?:Mc)?[A-Z][^A-Z]*`.*

Comment: In this case Mc is the only one.  I know how I would do it correctly but this is a hack.  grr..

Comment: OK - how bout 3 letters or more in the middle??